# Multisite problem with unexisting paths to CSS etc

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, urls, site-url, paths

I have the multisite Wordpress site:

*domain.com/siteA*

*domain.com/siteB*

Now when the post is published on main site (domain.com), it looks fine because bunch of resources are OK path:

```
https://domain.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.css?ver=5.7.2
```

and that URL actually exist.

However, all my subsites create automatically resources links like this:

```
https://domain.com/siteA/wp-includes/css/dashicons.css?ver=5.7.2
https://domain.com/siteB/wp-includes/css/dashicons.css?ver=5.7.2
```

Notice it cosiders domain.com/siteA to be the root, and just concate the rest...

**And everything on the page is rendered like that! And that URL and bunch of other URLs doesn't exist, so my CSS cracks and who knows what else...**

Here's my web.config part (Wordpress gave me that code when I was setting up Multisite option and it runs on IIS)

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Are your subsites using a child theme?

Comment: I wouldn't know yet. My mission is just to set it up. We'll see later about design (I'm totally noob for WP) but I guess we'll use separate themes for separate subsites